# Node-line minimum distance: draw the minimum distance point location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, map-drawing

I am working with a layer of nodes and a layer of lines.

I would need a tool able to find and draw, for some couples node-line, the location of the closest point laying on the line to this node.

If possible, I would also like to create such a feature in another layer, or at get the point coordinates.

I have been looking for a similar geoprocessing tool in ArcToolbox -> Proximity, but I did not find anything that could suit my need, since the "Near" tool just provide me with distances values.

Is there a tool in ArcMap able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near tool also gives you nearx and neary coordinates.

Convert them to points and merge with original points.

Use points to line tool and pointid to construct your lines